# WordPress API returns error when trying to get Featured Image

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, get, wordpress-rest-api

I am using the wordpress rest api for the first time with a react frontend. I can get the text and render it fine. However when I make the GET request I get this object for the featured media:

```
"_embedded": {
    "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
            "code": "rest_post_invalid_id",
            "message": "Invalid post ID.",
            "data": {
                "status": 404
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I properly retrieve the featured image so I don't get this message?

Here is my GET request:

```
let dataURL = "http://localhost:81/wp-json/wp/v2/movies?_embed";
fetch(dataURL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            movies: res
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following code will help you to get the featured images of all sizes. Please paste the code in functions.php.

```
//ADD FEATURED IMAGE WITH ALL SIZE
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'tris_endpoints_featured_images' );
function tris_endpoints_featured_images() {
    register_rest_field(  get_post_types() ,
        'featured_images',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'tris_endpoints_featured_images_cb',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}
function tris_endpoints_featured_images_cb( $object, $field_name, $request ) {

    if(has_post_thumbnail($object[ 'id' ])){
        $image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
        foreach ($image_sizes as $key => $size) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $object[ 'id' ]), $size );
            $all_images[$size]= $image[0];
        }

        return $all_images;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```